# performance issue with websocket.send() in python asyncio server

Tags: websocket, python-asyncio

**What I'm doing:** I'm sending data from a python server to the browser over a websocket connection. In server I'm using websockets and asyncio.
I get the data from a pub/sub system as json strings and forward the messages to the clients with `await websocket.send(message)`.

**My problem:** `await websocket.send(message)` is taking too long. 
What I mean with *too long*: a message of 1,5MB is received from the pub/sub system with a frequency of 16Hz (~ every 63ms). And `await websocket.send(message)` is taking up to 90ms to forward the message to one client. 
So my queue is getting full and the incoming messages on browser are obsolete.

Does anyone have an idea what can be done to "speed up" the sending process? Because I would prefer not to throw any messages...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try to use Gunicorn to have several instances of your http server. Do you use Nginx? It can improve speed and quality of your http ops.

Comment: I don't. I'm running the server locally. Would you still recomend I create several instances?